# Access XML elements with names containing a period/dot in FreeMarker templates

Tags: xml, spring, xml-parsing, freemarker

I have an XML in the form:

```
<root>
<x.y>
data
<x.y>
</root>
```

I need to access the value 'data' using freemarker(ftl) templates. If we try to access this using '.' notation it should be:

${root.x.y}

But this do not work. How can this be done.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `root["x.y"]`? I don't use FreeMarker, but FWIW, see http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/dgui_template_exp.html

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't it just be:
>
> > root["x.y"]

**References**

- [Imperative XML processing > Learning by example: Using XPath expressions](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html#autoid_72)