# how to read text in child elements if the parent element's name has dots in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have an xml document that I would like to parse using freemarker. The XML document itself was auto generated using SAX in my smooks script. This smooks script created the following XML with element names derived from the actual java package names that I have in my workspace.

```
<map>
    <entry>
        <string>RunReportMsg</string>
        <com.web.ws.messages.v1__2.RunReportMsg>
            <analyticsReport>
                <columns>
                    <com.web.ws.objects.v1__2.ReportColumn>
                        <dataType>
                            <id>
                                <id>10</id>
                            </id>
                        </dataType>
                    </com.web.ws.objects.v1__2.ReportColumn>
                </columns>
            <analyticsReport>
        </com.web.ws.messages.v1__2.RunReportMsg>
    </entry>
</map>
```

A similar question has been posted on this site about this. But I cannot figure out how this would solve my problem.

[Access XML elements with names containing a period/dot in FreeMarker templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638020/access-xml-elements-with-names-containing-a-period-dot-in-freemarker-templates/20334724)

I know how to access "RunReportMsg" text in the element "string".

${map.entry.string}

How do I access data in the following child element using dotted notation in freemarker? As the element "com.web.ws.messages.v1__2.RunReportMsg" has multiple periods, I am not sure how to traverse down through further child elements. I need a way to find out the number in the following "id" element.

```
<id>10</id>
```

I read the documentation on expressions in freemarker site on ".vars". I am not sure if this applies to my case.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
${map.entry["com.web.ws.messages.v1__2.RunReportMsg"].analyticsReport.columns["com.web.ws.objects.v1__2.ReportColumn"].dataType.id.id}
```